# How to properly type client.post response in django test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, typing

```
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def my_test(
        self,
        client,
    ):
        with monkeypatch_requests(resp_json={'values': []}):
            r: JsonResponse = client.post(
                self.endpoint,
                self.request_payload,
                content_type='application/json',
            )
        assert r.status_code == 201, r.content
        assert r.json() == {'key': value}
```

PyCharm is complainging `Unresolved attribute reference 'json' for class 'JsonResponse'`, but I can use it.

When I run the test in debugger and hover over `json` I can see `functools.partial(<bound method ClientMixin._parse_json of <django.test.client.Client object at 0x7f3b81399d30>>, <JsonResponse status_code=201, "application/json">)`

Comment: This is just the type inference system that can not handle the meta-programming part of Django, and thus got confused. Since Python is a strong dynamic language, the type inference can not determine types fully, as a consequence of Rice's theorem.

Comment: I think the problem is that `JsonResponse` is something you return from your own Django views, but the test client just deals with WSGI request/responses and then [adds back](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5aa4c0b67549f1d7ab649f53ac782d8de3e6a87c/django/test/client.py#L950) some of the extended attributes from the Django response classes that you expect to find, like `json` method. So annotation is wrong (it's not a `JsonResponse`) and probably better to just omit it.  It's not so much that type inference can't cope, it's that the Django test client isn't written to be type checked.

Comment: Here's what we did in django stubs to resolve it: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/test/client.pyi#L157. Please note the comment on a previous line: it's a **fake** class which does not exist on runtime. It's underscored for this reason. If you need it in your custom annotation (though in this MRE you just should keep `r` unannotated and specify type for `client` instead) - `if TYPE_CHECKING: from django.test.client import _MonkeyPatchedWSGIResponse` + annotations future-import or quoted name everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The json method is added to the response object by the django test client.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.json
https://github.com/django/django/blob/80a5667c50d12b27a031a9ce0408a5b81bc4e684/django/test/client.py#L950

It is not a method of `django.http.JsonResponse` and that's why PyCharm is complaining.